# Activation of the HTML5 Pattern Attribute with websockets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, websocket

As a total newbie to web-based programming, I'm having trouble understanding why the `pattern` attribute field below fails to check the validity of the text field due to my javascript.

```
<form id="aForm">
    <input type="text" pattern="^[ a-zA-Z0-9,#.-]+$" id="address" title="Standard address"/>        
<input type="submit" id="open" value="Start"/>
</form>
```

The form contents are then sent to a javascript file which then sends it to the server via a `websocket` as in the code fragment below. However it ignores validating the form through the `pattern` attribute.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#open").click(function(evt) {          
          evt.preventDefault();
          var form = $('#aForm').serialize();
          webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9999/mh");
          webSocket.onopen = function()
          {
             webSocket.send(form);
          };
          REST OF CODE....
```

It seems that for some reason this prevents the text from being checked before it's sent. I would  like to know why and how to ensure that the form is validated by the `pattern` attribute.

Thanks

Comment: for good measure, please rewrite your input field to insert spaces between adjacent attributes (e.g. change `id="address"title="Standard address"` to `id="address" title="Standard address"`)

Comment: @EliranMalka; made the changes. It must have compacted when I copied it over.

Comment: Bind the javascript sending to `$('#aForm').submit()` instead of `$('#open').click()`.

Comment: @DCoder: Thanks that has solved the problem and works as expected. Thanks for your help for all my questions. If you want to answer this  then I would be able to upvote it and accept your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML5 form validation is only performed when you're trying to actually [submit the form](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#form-submission-algorithm), or when you explicitly use JavaScript to validate it<sup>1</sup>.

Since your JavaScript is bound to a different event (button click), form validation is not performed at that point. You can solve this by:

1. binding your submission to the form's `submit` event instead of button click, or
2. using the [form validation API](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#the-constraint-validation-api) at the very beginning of your script.

I strongly recommend the first option. It makes more semantic sense and works right when the form is submitted though other methods (I don't remember if the button click will be simulated when someone presses Enter in the text field, and it definitely won't be triggered if JavaScript calls `$('#aForm').submit()` programmatically...).

---

<sup>1</sup> At least, those are the only places I noticed - it's possible there are other events/circumstances when validation is done as well.